# Quantity value on initial page with web standard

Tags: html, paypal

I have very simple Entry Order page with dropdown choice depending on age and the Pay Now button.
Rather than change the quantity on the PayPal Page, I would like to show a Quantity TextBox (with a default value of 1) below the DropDown and pass the value then to the PayPal Page.

Here is my html:

```
<body style="border-style:double; text-align:center;">
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" runat="server">
    <div><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="WTFZKTFE95PDG"/>
<table align="center">
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Registration Fees"/><b>Registration Fees</b></td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="14 Years and over">14 Years and over £20.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="under 14 Years">under 14 Years £15.00 GBP</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table><br /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online."/>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The pay button works. I guess I need an input tag asking for a Quantity in the TextBox but I am not sure how to pass that through to the PayPal site (Something like the name "on0" above. (I am quite new to Paypal)

Answer (score 1):

The variable that you would want to use to pass over the quantity, would be "quantity".  So you could just add a line of code similar to that below.

```
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" maxlength="5" value="1">
```

Comment: Brilliant - many thanks. I didnt think it would be so simple!